# SQL Master Table multiple left joins with Key-Value Pair Look ups

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, sql-server-2016

**Application - Legacy Enterprise System designed 20 yrs back**

I have a Product table with 50+ Rows where each column is an attribute, like

```
ID, Name, Brand, Category, Category, Gender, Item Code, Color Code......
```

Now most(around 43/50) of the columns have a key(or id) of the value (e.g. For Brand, key **b02** is stored, which translates to **Brown Bag** Brand, Key-Value is stored in different table)

This design is not exactly EAV, but different one done in a legacy application by a 3rd part application.

We are trying to get the data out of the DB into more Report/Analytics Friendly Format where-by I join each key based column in Master Table with Key-Value (using left join) and arrive at final table and store in different DB for Reporting.

This is working fine for smaller set, but if the data is large (>20K Rows), its getting slow as there are too many left joins

I see no option other than this approach, but if any one can give me more ideas to make it more efficient and fast, it will be helpful.

```
SELECT Product.id, Product.name, s1.value as 'Brand', s2.value as 'Category'
  , s3.value as 'Gender'
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN Attribute s1 ON s1.id = Product.brand AND s1.attribute = 'brand'
LEFT JOIN Attribute s2 ON s2.id = Product.category AND s2.attribute = 'category'
LEFT JOIN Attribute s3 ON s3.id = Product.gender AND s3.attribute = 'gender'

... 40 more
```

Comment: Add a close query

Comment: And please [Post The Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: Sorry @DaleBurrell , i cannot share anything as there are some NDA with vendor/company, I wish I can share everything

Comment: Unfortunately performance is a very unique to a specific query/database, so its pretty hard to offer generic advice that will help.

Comment: is my approach the only way or can I try anything?

Comment: From the limited information available the only suggestion I can offer is to inspect your execution plan yourself and see what is taking the most time and whether an index might reduce it. If you are lucky the execution plan may even suggest some indexes.

Comment: Re: NDA it is trivial to search and replace table/column/database and other names in plan XML. What else could possibly be NDA? The data types you chose or the number of spaces you use for indentation? Also I'd really avoid `column as 'alias'` syntax because that looks like a string literal *and* that form is deprecated in some contexts. If you need to quote an identifier, the more recognizable form is `[square brackets]`.

Comment: Anyway the pain here is not really in writing the query, that is easy enough to automate, but rather in **reading** the Attributes table **40 times**, especially since a scan is likely. There are ways to pivot (either with `PIVOT` explicitly or with `MAX(CASE` forms), so that at least you only have to read that table a single time (even if that single time is a massive scan).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I will try the PIVOT Option and see if there is improvement

Comment: @AaronBertrand : We are working for a customer who is really fuzzy abt these things and we has 2-3 instances, I will try to get as close details as possible

Comment: using SQL Fiddle can you give us a replicable example of your issue because the snipped of code and then ...40 more doesnt really give enough of an example in order to help you.  I have been doing a LOT of performance tuning in some of the places I have been working recently and there are ways where you can easily speed things up but its having that replicable object AND test data that will enable better help.

Answer (score 2):

One way that will probably improve this query's performance is to use conditional aggregation instead of multiple joins:

```
SELECT   P.id
        ,P.name
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN A.Id = P.brand AND A.attribute = 'brand' THEN A.value END) as 'Brand'
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN A.Id = P.category AND A.attribute = 'category' THEN A.value END) as 'Category'
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN A.Id = P.gender AND A.attribute = 'gender' THEN A.value END) as 'Gender'
        -- 40 more
FROM Product As P
LEFT JOIN Attribute As A
    ON A.id IN(P.brand, P.category, P.gender /* 40 more */) 
    AND A.attribute IN('brand', 'category', 'gender' /* 40 more */)    
-- The group by clause must contain all the columns that are not translated using the attribute table
GROUP BY P.id, P.name
```

Comment: I wish that there were a SQL function for this that did it without all the comparison operations  like an aggregate COALESCE.  Does any SQL language have that?